# Is there any bilinear Poincaré/Sobolev inequality?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, inequalities, sobolev-spaces, linear-pde

Is the following, I call it bilinear Poincaré inequality,  true?

Let $\Omega$ be an open bounded set in $\mathbf R^n\DeclareMathOperator{\dL}{d\!}$. There exists $C > 0$ such that for any $u, v \in H^2(\Omega)$,
\begin{equation}
\int_{\Omega} (u - \bar{u})^2(v - \bar{v})^2 \dL x \le C\int_{\Omega} \lvert Du\rvert^2\lvert Dv\rvert^2 \dL x
\end{equation}
where $\bar{u}$, $\bar{v}$ are the mean values of $u$ and $v$ over $\Omega$ respectively.

**If the above is false, is there any other form of "bilinear Poincare inequality" or "bilinear Sobolev inequality" and even for $p$ other than 2?**

Comment: Your edit changes nothing. It in fact makes it easier to construct a counterexample.

Answer (score 13):

**Note: My answer was posted before the question was edited to a different question. My counterexample still works for edit 6 of the question.**

Let $\Omega=(0,2)$. Let $$\DeclareMathOperator{\dL}{d\!}u(x)=\begin{cases}0&\text{ if }x<1\\
x-1&\text{ if }x>1\end{cases}$$
and
$$
v(x)=\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x<1\\
1&\text{ if }x>1\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
\int_0^2 u(x)\dL x=\frac{1}{2}
$$
and
$$
\int_0^2 v(x)\dL x=\frac{3}{2}
$$
so $\bar u=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\bar v=\frac{3}{4}$. However
$$
\begin{split}
\int_0^2(u(x)-\bar u)(v(x)-\bar v)\dL x & =\int_0^1 -\frac{1}{4}\left(x-\frac{3}{4}\right)\dL x+\int_1^2 \left(x-\frac{5}{4}\right)\frac{1}{4} \dL x \\
&=\frac{1}{16}+\frac{1}{16}=\frac{1}{8}.
\end{split}
$$
But
$$
\int_0^2 |u'(x)||v'(x)|\dL x=0.
$$

Comment: More generally, for the purposes of testing a putative inequality $|X| \leq CY$, asking "Does $Y=0$ imply $X=0$?" is often a good starting point, since this is a necessary (though far from sufficient) condition for the inequality to hold.

Comment: By version 2, do you mean [version 6](https://mathoverflow.net/revisions/453616/6)? (You can link to the edit history to specify which version(s) your answer applies to.)

Answer (score 2):

From a higher level point of view, the Poincare inequality is about comparing **seminorms** of functions. For example, it is reasonable to expect something like:

$$\DeclareMathOperator{\dL}{d\!}\int_\Omega ( u - \overline u )^p \dL x \leq C \int_\Omega | D u |^p \dL x$$

Your suggested inequality looks like trying to compare two scalar products, except it has been modified on the right-hand side to be positive.